# Hazelcast: management center not work

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using [this](https://github.com/tmatyashovsky/hazelcast-samples-javaday-kyiv) example of HazelCast, where management center configured with help of

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    Config hazelcastConfig = new Config("HazelcastPresentation");
    hazelcastConfig.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true).setUrl("http://localhost:9090/mancenter");
    // ... another configs ...
    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig);
}
```

But when I go to `http://localhost:9090/mancenter` I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: what is the import associated with the "Config" class?  Can't seem to find reference to this in any public documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to download Management center war from here http://hazelcast.com/products/management-center/

and start it with command `java -jar mancenter-x.x.x.war 9090 mancenter`

Next should be straightforward.

Cheers,
Vik